# Springboot 3.0 cannot save data in Postgres, gives error no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

In my multi module spring-boot application there is a common module with a config file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan("com.sample.folder")
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample.folder")
public class CommonConfig
```

Under the common module under "folder" package I also have a entity, respository and a service class. The service class is autowired from my main application class which is in another module.

```
@Transactional
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {

      @Autowired
      private Repository repository;
      
    
      @Override
      public void saveInfo(String type, Timestamp ts, String data) {
    
        Entity entity =
            new Entity(new EntityId(type, ts), data);
        var returnedObject = repository.saveAndFlush(entity);
    
      }
```

My repository:

```
@Repository
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Entity, EntityId>
```

My Entity with Composite PrimaryKey:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample")
public class Entity implements Serializable {
  @EmbeddedId private EntityId id;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
  private String data;

  public Entity(){}
  public Entity(EntityId id, String data) {
    this.id = id;
    this.data = data;
  }

}
```

If I try to use `save` method then it gives no error but doesn't save in db, but if I use `saveAndFlush` which is supposed to commit gives error:

```
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

Already using @Transactional annotation. The expectation is spring would initialise `Transaction Manager` and since autowired would connect and post data to db but not happeing.

The property file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=sample


spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

The postgres db is running on docker. Nevertheless there is a cassandra connection as well, I don't understand if that can be a problem.

Additionally I have noticed the hibernate only performs select query and doesn't execute insert.

Comment: 1. Don't use EnableTransactionManagement because EnableJPARepositorirs take care of this. 2. Check your repository. It should be an interface extending JPARepository. (Your code snippet of service is just illustrative, right?)

Comment: Latest version of Spring Boot is 3.0 so there's something wrong with your title ;)

Comment: that is illustrative that's right. I have updated the question@Mar-Z